# avoiding repeat data in hCard

Tags: html, microformats

I'm revamping my work's Employee Directory, adding `hCard` data to each employee's listing.

An issue I haven't been able to figure out is how to avoid duplicating information, such as `organization-name` and `organization-unit`.

Here's a trimmed-down example of my code:

```
<div id="hcard-business" class="vcard">
  <div class="adr">
    <div class="org fn"><a class="url" href="http://www.business.com/">Business</a></div>
    <div class="street-address">123 Business Street</div>
    <div>
      <span class="locality">City</span>, 
      <abbr class="region" title="State">ST</abbr>,
      <span class="postal-code">99999</span>,
      <span class="country-name">USA</span></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<table class="contact">
  <thead>
    <tr><th colspan="4">Marketing Department</th></tr>
    <tr class="head"><th>NAME</th><th>TITLE</th><th>PHONE</th><th>EMAIL</th></tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr id="hcard-employee1" class="vcard odd">
      <td class="fn">Employee Name</td>
      <td class="title">Director</td>
      <td class="tel">907-335-1243</td>
      <td>
        <a class="email" href="mailto:employee.name@business.com">employee.name@business.com</a> 
        <span class="org fn hidden">
          <span class="organization-name">Business Name</span>, 
          <span class="organization-unit">Marketing</span>
        </span>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="hcard-employee2" class="vcard even">
      <td class="fn">Employee Name</td>
      <td class="title">Assistant</td>
      <td class="tel">907-335-1243</td>
      <td>
        <a class="email" href="mailto:employee.name@business.com">employee.name@business.com</a> 
        <span class="org fn hidden">
          <span class="organization-name">Business Name</span>, 
          <span class="organization-unit">Marketing</span>
        </span>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

What I'm attempting to do is trim out the `hidden` span from the last `<td>`, grabbing `organization-name` from the business' `hCard` and `organization-unit` from the `<thead>`.

I've pretty much scoured [microformats.org](http://microformats.org) looking for an example of what I'm attempting, but no luck. I've even peeked at several of their "microformats in the wild" list, but the few sites I found there with multiple employee lists were using the same `hidden` method with duplicate information that I've used in my example.

Is what I'm attempting to do even possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From a semantic standpoint, it is incorrect to try to avoid duplication. Being as verbose as possible (even in the name of duplicating code) is the most effective way to be as explicit as possible. Your best option is to hide it as you're doing. There is no way--according to the hCard spec--to reference information elsewhere in the document.

Hope this clears things up.

Comment: Thanks, this makes perfect sense to me now.

Comment: If you already knew that, you can correct your awnser and I'll delete my own.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should separate things. One card for your company, and one card for each employee.

Repeating organization-name, organization-unit on each employee card is not a problem at all.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the microformat include pattern:

http://microformats.org/wiki/include-pattern

All you have to do is to reference the parent vcard using a anchor, like:

```
<span class="item"><a href="#vcard" class="include">Somename</a></span>
```

I did not found any information about Google supporting the include pattern, but google is parsing my pages without any warnings at http://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/richsnippets and my page seems ok in the index.